# Python: Tkinter not displaying my image or UI

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to create a user interface with a picture in its top right corner. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
import base64 as b64

class my_ui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.intialize()

    def intialize(self):
        self.grid()

        #Welcome
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Welcome to my UI", anchor='center',fg='white',bg='blue')
        label.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,rowspan=2,sticky='EW')

        #Buttons
        button = tk.Button(self,text="Button 1",command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='W')

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        print("You clicked the button!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = my_ui(None)

    #Logo URL - just a smiley face
    URL = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCItlNQe0QaiuhkADUwgVTpx-Isaym6RAP06PHkzBe2Yza3a4rYIkHuB8"
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()
    b64_data = b64.encodestring(raw_data)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)

    logo = tk.Label(app, image=photo)
    logo.image = photo                  # To save it in memory
    logo.pack()                         # If I exclude this line, UI works fine.
    app.title('My User Interface')
    app.mainloop()
```

I am pulling a .gif from the web and returning a PhotoImage with my function. When I run this, I get no errors - rather, my tkinter window does not appear whatsoever. When I take out the line I mentioned in the comment, my UI comes up fine (buttons, but no image) with no errors.

I am unsure of what exactly the absence of the window means. I am running Python 3.4.1 on Mac OSx. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `tk.PhotoImage` can have problem with `garbage collector` which remove `PhotoImage` created in function if it is not assigned to global variable or to existing object.

Comment: It seems that all of the image work (from the URL variable declaration to the *return tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)* line) in the MyImage() function is not working as intended. After some testing, it seems that when I take these lines out of the function and run them globally, I can produce a tkinter window with my picture. I will try this approach in my main program to see if I get my intended result. Strange how the .Label() function does not seem to see my PhotoImage object when produced from my own function.

Comment: It is not problem with `Label` but with `PhotoImage` and `garbage collector`. For some reason `garbage collector` treats `PhotoImage` created in function as unnecessery element in memory.

Comment: I understand now. I have eliminated the `MyImage()` function and have placed the `PhotoImage` code in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` section. I still get the same result, no tkinter window.

Comment: Why don't you put all in class instead of mix class with `__main__`.

Comment: You can't mix `grid()` with `pack()` in one `window` or one `Frame` - now you use `grid()` for `Button` and one `Label` and `pack()` for another `Label`. `grid()` and `pack()` are different `layout managers`.

Comment: met the same problem. Any updates since this time?

Answer (score 0):

When a `tk.PhotoImage` object gets garbage collected, the image is "released", so to speak. The image is still technically being used, so it's not destroyed, but it will get completely blanked out. Replace your `return` line with:

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
return photo
```

Just be sure to declare `photo` as a global variable.

Comment: I have changed my MyImage function to return the PhotoImage object as a variable as described above. There is still no tkinter window that pops up. As far as I can tell, this does not seem to change the output of my code.